# Scroll to hidden element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a hidden input field, inside a table td, and when I select option A I want the browser to scroll down to that visible input that is inside a `table td`.
I have tried code bellow, but something is not working correct.
ID of the input field: `#id_a-1-host`

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#id_a-1-host').offset().top},'slow');
```

It scrolls down but only a little bit. It is not scrolling down to the input field.

Comment: give the id to the td itself.

Comment: Hi! Its not working to give ID to the td ;(.

Comment: @Jai You can't navigate by giving `id` to the `<td>`...

Answer (score 5):

The `scrollTop` is based on the visibility and if you have it hidden, using `display: none`, it is not available in the viewport, so it won't work as expected. It is always better to use a named anchor in these cases:

```
<a name="id-a-off" id="id-a-off">
```

Or even an empty span will do:

```
<span name="id-a-off" id="id-a-off"></span>
```

Make sure this is in a static parent.

Also, if you have a static header or something set up, you need to **add that height** as well:

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: jQuery('#id_a-1-host').offset().top - staticHeaderHeight
}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Hi! I have name="id-a-off" on the input, but is not a a tag or a span. It does no differens if I use staticHeaderHeight.

Comment: @Tony How did you use `staticHeaderHeight`?

Comment: I tested with var staticHeaderHeight = jQuery(window).height() - 250;

Comment: @Tony `staticHeaderHeight = $("header").height()`

Comment: The strange is that its working when I have my firebug on. Very strange

Comment: Ha ha ha... @Tony

Comment: Its not working, and Im trying to fix the problem :).

Comment: @Tony Ah okay... Will wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the .closest(':visible') element. It goes up into the parents untill it finds a visible one.

Tip: If you use .closest() it includes the element itself too

```
return $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(el).closest(':visible').offset().top
}, 400);
```